# How to remove lines containing % in Pig?

Tags: hdfs, apache-pig

I have file that contain data in 3ed column i wanna filter that data using pig and perform other oprations on it.

string is like *%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B0* and all the other strings are similer but containing % char.

How can i Filter data what i am doing is

```
Z = FILTER A BY not (a3  matches '.*%%D0%%*.');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that a3 is a Chararray. Then, you should filter like this:

```
Z= FILTER A BY NOT a3 MATCHES '.*%D0%.*';
```

As far as I know, there is no need to escape % and you should put only one % if you want to filter those that do not contain %D0%. However, if you want to filter those expressions that do not contain %%D0%% your expression should work fine.

Comment: it is not working but i found the solution thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case:

```
 Z = FILTER A BY NOT a3 matches '.*.[%].*.';
```

by using this filter i am able to remove lines containing '%'